# Editing Multiple Rows in NSTableView Using Bindings

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have done quite a bit of searching around but haven't been able to find much on this topic.  Ideally I would like users to select multiple rows and then be able to edit all the values of a certain column for the selected rows.  I am currently trying to use Cocoa bindings (but could use DataSource if necessary).

If I select multiple rows and try to double click on a row nothing happens.  I know this is possible using a popup window but was hoping for a solution within the table.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you set any doubleClick action? Look at NSTableView delegate. Dfine some action method that does something with selectionIndexes. Code can make this easier.

Comment: I did not consider that.  I was really hoping functionality like this was already built in but it appears it is not.

Comment: There's no default action for it. NSTableView is incredibly flexible and is probably one of the defining parts of AppKit but you will need to write some code. Bindings will get you 80 to 90% and then they get hard for doing a lot and handling edge cases. The delegate and DataSource protocols for NSTableView are immensely powerful.

Comment: It looks like to do this I need to set the target to my controller class.  Does this mean it is not possible to mix the bindings with a custom double click event?

Comment: Nevermind, I was mistaken, it appears I can mix and match.

Comment: It's more flexible than that even. You could set it per row or cell/view or just forward it up the responder chain or target FirstResponder.